# Uploading documents using Sharepoint Designer Workflow to different Site Collection Using Rest API Web Service

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Is there any way to publish a document across multiple site collection using REST call in SharePoint Designer Workflow? The requirement is like we need to upload a document in a site collection and it should automatically get uploaded to different site collection. We want achieve this using SP Designer 2013 and HTTP Web Service.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are plenty of out of the box servcies that can help you with that. The one you will need are  _api/web/lists and Files/add. Full reference for web services you will find here:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn593591.aspx

Those 2 links should help you to achieve what you need. 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/uksharepoint/2013/04/20/uploading-files-using-the-rest-api-and-client-side-techniques/

http://johnliu.net/blog/2014/2/19/using-sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow-to-copy-file-via-res.html

Comment: Can you please give me an example with the REST query on how the query should look like.